# My dad forces me to read quran and learn about islam

Tags: quran, salat, practical-islam, allah, parents

I'm 14. I am a muslim, but my dad forces me to learn quran and learn prayers from head. It makes me like islam less and takes me away from god. He never listens and doesn't understand. I want to learn all of this at my own pace, and when I'm ready. What should I say or do?

Comment: At your age your basic Islamic education should have been accomplished that means you should know the prayer and perform it on your own and know about fasting and experienced it too. You are mature or close to that and would therefore be accountable for your deeds (and misdeeds) that's why your father seemingly is pushing you.

Comment: I was not born a muslim. I was a christian until I started living with my dad. I was a christian for 12 years. I am not from a islamic country neither do I live in one right now. It's very hard but my dad doesn't understand that.

Comment: "What should I" questions attract subjective answers and are a bad fit on stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Your father knows better, because learning Quran in a young age is much better than learning it in a late age, and most of grown up men regret not learning Quran while they were young. My advice to you is to do what your fathers says, because Quran is the words of Allah our creator, and it contains all the wisdom you need in this life, and you won't regret it, you'll love it more and more.
Try to read some verses every day for example after the Prayer of Asr, and you'll learn to understand it better every day. And know that Quran will come in the resurrection day and saves you from Hell, because you were from the readers in Dunya, and the readers of Quran are special for Allah, as He will take them under the shade when the rest of disbelievers stays under the burning sun of that day.

Comment: I was not born a muslim. I was a christian until I started living with my dad. I was a christian for 12 years. I am not from a islamic country neither do I live in one right now. It's very hard but my dad doesn't understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Teachings of Christianity is very similar in essence. We believe we are descendants of Adam and Eve and there is only one God.

Only difference Christianity believes Jesus peace be upon him was God but we believe he was a prophet and messenger of God. Jesus never claimed to be Lord but messenger of your lord . We believe in mother Mary as a virgin , miraculous birth and Jesus (pbuh) as prophet and performing many miracles .

So reading Quran and learning about it will only make you understand better and elevate yourself in knowledge from others.

Most people only follow religion of their fathers or mothers without questioning . I myself questioned everything and reading Quran gave me enlightenment. It could really give you peace and contentment.

Although I don’t agree with your fathers approach . Hidayet is only from Allah. Tell your father that .

But please don’t give up on reading word of your creator because it will benefit you and guide you in life like no other.